# Edit existing PM2 process

Tags: javascript, node.js, digital-ocean, pm2

I have an existing PM2 process that I would like to add the "--max-memory-restart" setting to. How can I do that? The process was created from the command line without a JSON file.

If I were creating a new process I would just run:

`PM2 start [process name] --max-memory-restart 700M` or whatever

How can I do the same for an existing process? How can I confirm that it works?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you cant stop it and start it or restart it?

Comment: If your server is an http server u can use Apache Benchmarking Tool and make thousand of request and if your server restart u can check in pm2 status.

Answer (score 8):

To change your existing PM2 process. you can use this command:
`pm2 restart [existing name] --max-memory-restart 700M`

To check if it affect or not, you can set it with low memory to restart (like 30M). Then check restart time by : `pm2 ls` command.

Sorry for my bad English. Hope it help.

Answer (score 4):

For **0 downtime** you can now also use (more preferable in production):

```
pm2 reload my_current_name --name my_new_name --max-memory-restart 700M
```

**For differences, please see:**

[What is the difference between pm2 restart and pm2 reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883269/what-is-the-difference-between-pm2-restart-and-pm2-reload)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit this setting 'WITHOUT' restarting the process, there doesn't seem to be a way to do it. PM2's docs don't list any way to do this, such options have to be stated along with starting the process.